# a c++ timer is blocking my entire class?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

i guess there is some reasonable and an easy solution. So for instance i have:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

time(2)

// anything else in the about class....

//return code

}
```

The problem is that the whole application almost freezes and i cannot do anything but "wait for the timer". 
How can i make the timer runs irrespectively to any other operation? 10x!

Answer (score 5):

You want to do a [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) call and either give it a pointer to a callback function, or respond to the WM_TIMER message that comes back.